# How many days can I store in 4 bytes with millisecond precision?

Tags: byte

now I meet a issue to research how many days can I store in 4 bytes with millisecond precision. who knows that? thanks

Comment: Basically 2**32 ms in days? Circa 7 weeks. That's basic arithmetic, not programming.

Comment: [Try Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=2%5E32+milliseconds+in+days).

Comment: 49,71026962962962962962962962963 days = 7,1014670899470899470899470899471 weeks

Comment: @Rawling I love Google's calculator

Answer (score 10):

4 bytes = 2^32 = 4294967296
1 day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 miliseconds = 86400000

4294967296 / 86400000 = 49.71026962962962962962962962963

or about 49 days 17 hours 2 minutes and 47 seconds

Comment: Nice to give decomposition in days an hours.

Answer (score 3):

1 byte has 8 bits. 1 bit can hold 2 different values (0 or 1) so 1 byte can hold 2^8 different values.

There are 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds in a day.

The rest of the math should be trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Find out this way in Java:

```
System.out.println(((long)Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MIN_VALUE) / 1000f / 60 / 60 / 24);
```